Render problem after updating an dictionary, Vue 3, Django, DRF
When i try to apply filters page's content doesn't update.
First GET request is being sent after you move to localhost:8000/catalog/
I get another after setting the filters and sending a GET request to my API, and the respone is fine,but the DOM doesnt't update
Update 1/11/24:
here's my html code that has to update
<div class="Cards">
    <!-- Получаем товары по фильтрам -->
            <div v-for="card in catalogCards" class="Card" :key="card.id">
              <p>${ card }$</p>
              <a v-if="card.images && card.images.length" class="Card-picture" :href="'/product/' + card.id">
                <img :src="card.images[0].image" />
              </a>
              <a v-else class="Card-picture" :href="'/product/' + card.id">
                <img src="/static/frontend/assets/img/placeholder.png" alt="No Image" />
              </a>

              <div class="Card-content">
                <strong class="Card-title"><a :href="'/product/' + card.id">${ card.title }$</a></strong>
                <div class="Card-description">
                  <div class="Card-cost"><span class="Card-price">${ card.price }$</span></div>
                  <div class="Card-hover">
                    <a class="Card-btn" @click="addToBasket(card)">
                      <img src="/static/frontend/assets/img/icons/card/cart.svg" alt="cart.svg"/>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
</div>

that's my getCatalogs method:
getCatalogs(page = 1) {
            console.log("method getCatalogs called")
            const PAGE_LIMIT = 20
            const tags = this.topTags.filter(tag => !!tag.selected).map(tag => tag.id)
            console.log("tags:", tags)
            const min = document.querySelector('input[name=minPrice]').value
            const max = document.querySelector('input[name=maxPrice]').value
            console.log("min:", min, "max:", max)

            if (parseFloat(min) !== 0) {
                this.filter.minPrice = parseFloat(min);
            }
            if (parseFloat(max) !== 50000) {
                this.filter.maxPrice = parseFloat(max);
            }

            this.updateUrlWithFilters()

            this.getData("/api/catalog/", {
                filter: {
                    ...this.filter,
                    minPrice: parseFloat(min),
                    maxPrice: parseFloat(max)
                },
                currentPage: page,
                category: this.category,
                sort: this.selectedSort ? this.selectedSort.id : null,
                sortType: this.selectedSort ? this.selectedSort.selected : null,
                tags,
                limit: PAGE_LIMIT
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log("response from API (data):", data);

                // create new list for correct displaying of changes
                this.catalogCards = [...data.results.items];

                console.log("data.items:", data.results.items);
                console.log("catalogCards:", this.catalogCards);

                this.currentPage = data.currentPage;
                this.lastPage = data.lastPage;

            }).catch(error => {
                console.warn('couldnt get the catalog');
                console.log(error);
            })
        },

I have tried to use watch with force updating, but didn't work

"the DOM doesn't update".  what parts of the DOM?  we don't know what code is all related to the DOM except the obvious querySelectors. Is the selectors your issue? consider only including the minimal code to reproduce the issue. Include the relevant template code that should be updating.  querySelectors should generally be avoided with Vue, so properly using refs or v-model may be what you want to use instead.

I have updated the code, the part with cards of products has to update after i submit filters in another section of catalog.html
